# How to use range function to keep values in same line in helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, sprig-template-functions

I am trying to build configmap data out of values I have in values.yaml.

```
CASE 1:
values.yaml:
  example: abc xyz 
  servers: IP1 IP2 IP3
```

I want configmap data something like all the example domain forwarded to servers.

It would be really grateful if someone helps me out. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the format you currently have, `.Values.dns_servers` is already a string with space-separated values, which is the format you want out.  You don't need to split it to a list and write it out again.

```yaml
{{- if .Values.dns_servers }}
forward . {{ .Values.dns_servers }}
{{- end }}
```

Helm contains (almost all of) the extension functions in the [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) library, not all of which are in the Helm documentation proper.  If you do have this as a list, there is a [`join`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/string_slice.html) template function that can combine them together.

```yaml
{{- $dns_servers := splitList " " .Values.dns_servers }}
{{- if $dns_servers }}
forward . {{ join " " $dns_servers }}
{{- end }}
```

Rather than a space-separated string, you might find it easier to manipulate these values if you use native YAML lists in your `values.yaml` file.  Any valid YAML list syntax will work here, including formats that put the entire list on one line.

```yaml
# values.yaml, reformatted to use YAML lists and snakeCase names
dnsDomains: [abc,xyz]
dnsServers:
  - 10.10.10.10
  - 10.10.10.11
  - 10.10.20.20
```

As one final option, if you're very careful about the whitespace handling, you can put the templating anywhere you want, even in the middle of a line.

```yaml
{{- with .Values.dnsServers }}
forward .
{{- range . }} {{ . }}{{ end }}
{{- end }}
```

The important trick with this last example is that the `-` whitespace control before `range` also consumes the newline at the end of the previous line.  Then inside the `range` block, repeated once for each element and with no whitespace control, there is a space and a list element.  Finally after the very last `end` there is a newline.

You can double-check this with `helm template`, which will validate the YAML syntax and print out what got rendered (with `--debug` it will print it out even if it's invalid YAML).